# e books, websites, magazines, applications etc to learn qml

Tags: qml, ubuntu-sdk

I wish to learn ***qml*** so that I can code in **Ubuntu sdk** effectively.

Can you name some books, websites, apps etc to help me learn qml?

I have good experience of programming in C++, but not so in python.qml. Being part of Java, can knowledge of C++ help in learning qml (because people say its easy to learn Java having knowledge of C++)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this, for instance? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtquick-applicationdevelopers.html

in general, qt-project page should answer most of the doubts you don't find here in askubuntu, thought it answers more general questions about qml than this ubuntu questions site.
If you need ubuntu concrete implementations, you can take a look at launchpad already existing applications. For example, the core apps https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone-coreapps